Plone: How to Create/rename a folder that begins with a dot?
I need to create a folder that starts with a "." (dot), ".well-known/", in order to verify the client's Bluesky handle, not using the DNS panel.
But it seems that by default Plone does not accept any folder starting with a dot.
Any thoughts on how can I manage this?
I created the ".well-known" folder and added the "atproto-did" file, but in the URL the result appears as "https:// [domain] /well-known/atproto-did", without the dot in the name of the folder.

I managed to create a .test folder like this: In http://localhost:8080/Plone/en/manage_main -> Select type to add -> Folder -> Id: .test

this a task for the webserver/proxy, like nginx in front of Plone.
letsencrypt for example does the same more or less automatically for you.
In Plone you can try in ZMI to add a Folder and or Zope page template.
